# How to appending to the_content using add_filter with custom post type?

Tags: filters, the-content

I have a custom post type running fine, but some of the text in the page is the same for every post, so I want to add it in using a function.

I have this set up:

```
function new_default_content($content) {
global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'custom-post-type') {
    $content = 'Test text here';
    }
    return $content;
    }
add_filter('the_content', 'new_default_content');
```

However when I refresh the page, I only see "Text test here" and not the the post's content (from the_content).

If I comment out this function, the post content reappears. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're completely overwriting the content instead of appending it. You need to do something like `$content .= 'Test text here';` instead.

Comment: Much power in that period, thanks! Another question: I am using a plugin to display social buttons for Like, +1 etc and they are appearing above the new-default-content — is there a way to get the buttons to appear below? I assumed this filter would "chunk" the_content & new_default_content as one complete section.

Comment: Well, you're appending the new content, so it's going to appear afterward. You might try hooking the filter in at a higher priority to get it to process before the plugin does, because the plugin is also using the same filter.

Comment: Ah, I will look into the priorities thing — thanks again!

Comment: FYI I played around with the priority and that did the trick! Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

In Simple way `

```
               if ($post->post_type == 'custom-post-type') {
                   $new_content= 'Test text here';
                                }
                       return $content.$new_content;
```

Comment: Only code is not considered a good quality answer. You should explain what the code does and how it answers the question; in this way readers who are newbies in coding will understand your answer. Can you explain your code?